# Different SVD result in R and MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I am new to R and was trying SVD of a matrix. When I cross checked with MATLAB the V matrix of SVD showed different results. Is there an explanation I am missing or I did some wrong in R programming. Following are the screen shots of R and MATLAB. However the U and D matrix are similar

[image: SVD with R]

[image: SVD with MATLAB]

Comment: Check if Matlab is only showing 4 decimal digits (with rounding) but in memory these values have double precision.  Matrix V in R seems to have the last column missing (did you capture it?).  Overall they seem the same to me.

Comment: I am worried about the last missing column of V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`svd`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/svd.html) can accept `nu` and `nv` arguments specifying the size of `U` and `V` to emit. These default to `min(# of rows, # of cols)`, meaning by default in R the SVD is the “skinny” or economy-mode SVD, whereas Matlab defaults to the full SVD unless you ask for the skinny version.

Here’s how to get the full `V`: `S = svd(M, nu=3, nv=4)`. More generally, `nu=nrow(M)` and `nv=ncol(M)`.

Full example:

```
> M = matrix(c(2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3), nrow=3, ncol=4)
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    5    3    1
[2,]    3    1    4    2
[3,]    4    2    0    3
> S = svd(M, nu=3, nv=4)
> S$u
          [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.6486710  0.63810301  0.4147897
[2,] 0.5607706 -0.03225566 -0.8273427
[3,] 0.5145506 -0.76927506  0.3787527
> S$d
[1] 8.790352 3.524115 2.882763
> S$v
          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,] 0.5731120 -0.5384787 -0.04767577 -0.61588176
[2,] 0.5498331  0.4596073  0.69520488  0.05598925
[3,] 0.4765560  0.5065914 -0.71632725  0.05598925
[4,] 0.3769888 -0.4921046 -0.03595079  0.78384952
```

In this case, the Matlab and R SVD match! (In general they don’t need to match, since any rotation of both `U` and `V` is also an SVD.)

Comment: Thanx Ahmed...U and V are not unique so I understand...but I needed a full V...any book for R beginners u can suggest (besides online help) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t learn programming via books, I just write a lot of code and read a lot of docs . Recently I started doing some Project Euler and better yet, Cryptopals Crypto Challenge problems, to practice things that I wouldn’t otherwise know much about.

Answer (score 2):

In conclusion, they are the same.

Then, why do these matrices look different?

Recall how SVD decomposes a matrix into UΣV*.

The dimensions of the matrices are m x m, m x n, n x n respectively.

However, the Σ is a diagonal matrix, and only max(m,n) dimensions are required to represent the matrix.

When this reduction is done, either U or V* will have reduced dimensions depending on the size of m and n. For example, in this case Σ can be reduced to a 3 x 3 matrix, and V* will be a 3 x 4 matrix.

Finally, one can ask if this reduction results in loss of information. But, the "missing part" of the matrix can be recovered from the fact that they are unitary matrices.

Comment: Why does R skip one column of V ?

Comment: As I mentioned in this answer, this reduction does not result in loss of information. Why did R choose the reduction technique while MATLAB didn't is another question. I can say that it costs less memory because it obviously saves less data, but I guess this isn't a perfect explanation.

Comment: i have an iterative algorithm which requires SVD in each iteration and does some operation with the V matrix . What should i do ? reconstruct V again ?

Comment: If your algorithm really requires the whole matrix, I guess you can reconstruct the V matrix again although I think there is a better way like using a different svd library.